# iOS UITableView: Empty header and footer height?

Tags: ios, uitableview, header, height

to correctly embed a UITableView into a UIScrollView I need to know the exact height of the UITableView. I added the count of rows * rowHeight and the count of section headers * sectionTitleHeight, but this is still roughly 50px off the point. I guess it is caused by the empty table header and footer, but I can't find any information about how high they are...

Did I miss something in the UITableView class ref?

Thanks for any tips, 
nobi

Comment: UITableView is a UIScrollView itself why do you need to embed it inside another UIScrollView? This is a recipe for a lot of touch handling headaches.

Comment: There's dynamic stuff above the table which I could not fit into the view. Now, with more experience, I might try again putting this into the table's header view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `UITableView`'s `frame` variable and check its `size` member variable to see the exact size of your `UITableView` element.

```
CGSize tableSize = [table frame].size;
CGFloat tableHeight = tableSize.height;
CGFloat tableWidth = tableSize.width;
```

Comment: Alexander, this will only give you the frame currently occupied by the table on the view. It will not give you the size needed to display all rows.

Comment: I see what you mean. You can try making your table with a single element, get the size from the `frame` and then add `(n - 1)` * row height to get the size you want.

Comment: Alexander, thanks. Sounds like a rough workaround, but will work. I wonder how layouting views determine the size of their scrollbar - this requires knowledge of the overall size, and I hoped somebody knew how to get at this information. Anyway, I'll try your approach. Thanks, nobi

Comment: For the scroll bar they probably check the `contentSize`

Comment: Alexander, no - they don't. I just tried to embed a UITableView into a popover, and there I have the same issue: Size the popover to just the rectangle required to display the table. Using the tableview's (view's) contentSize gives me one row (instead of 8) and full-screen width where only a quarter is needed. So this still remains a mystery.